# Use $mdDialog stright from controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Trying to use the $mdDialog when login fails; currently I have injected $mdDialog and where my response fails I have added the following code:

**$mdDialog Code:**

```
$mdDialog.show( 
$mdDialog.alert()
.title('Username / password is incorrect')
.textContent(response.message)
.ok('Got it!'));
```

Any Idea what am I doing wrong ?

**My error**

```
$mdDialog.alert(...).title(...).textContent is not a function
```

**My controller (I don't think its necessary but just encase ):**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('authController', authController);

    authController.$inject = ['$scope','$state','AuthService','$mdDialog'];


    function authController($scope,$state,AuthService,$mdDialog) {

        $scope.login = login;
        $scope.user = {email: 'user', pass: 'pass'};

        function login(){

            this.dataLoading = true;

            AuthService.Login(this.user.email, this.user.pass, function (response) {

                console.log(response);

                if (response.success) {

                    $state.go("dashboard");

                } else {

                    $mdDialog.show( $mdDialog.alert().title('Username / password is incorrect').textContent(response.message)
                    .ok('Got it!'));

                }
            });         

        }

    };



})();
```

Comment: So is dialog not showing? Or you don't see any message in it?

Comment: Try it with alert variable instead of a nested call. i.e. create a var alert, set with all details and then show it like `$mdDialog.show(alert)`

Answer (score 0):

My knowledge is very limited but I managed to do this by setting up a separate function within my login function and calling it from my else.

```
function showAlert() {

    var alert;
    alert = $mdDialog.alert()
    .title('Attention,')
    .content('Incorrect username or password; please try agian!')
    .ok('Close');



    $mdDialog.show( alert )
    .finally(function() { 
       alert = undefined;
    });
}
```